# ViewGroup.LayoutParams Java android dot notation

Tags: java, android

I don´t understand the notation `VieuwGroup.LayoutParams`
This a subclass that extends `Object`...
I know it´s possible to do `class.field` or `class.method`
But this looks like `class.class` ? Is this some kind of inner class ?

Comment: Not exactly an inner class but you were close. This one is a static nested class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 1):

Classes like ViewGroup.LayoutParams are called nested classes.

They are often static, like this :

```
class MainClass{
    public static class NestedClass{
    }
};
```

You can also read these links for more info, or search Google for 'Java nested class'

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html
http://www.oursland.net/tutorials/java/innerclasses/

Comment: Actually, it's customary to only call **non-static** nested classes *inner classes*, while `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` is static.